# Call PopupMenu VB.NET Framework 2.0

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, vb6, vb6-migration, popupmenu

I have a project that I have converted from VB6 to .NET, using Visual Studio 2008 with the framework 2.0. In VB6 you can call a PopupMenu like so:

```
Call Me.PopupMenu(mnuEstimating)
```

I tired to use the same code in .NET but I get the error:

> 'PopupMenu' is not a member of 'frmEstimatePriority'.

I have looked around on the web and have seen ContextMenuStrip being used in place of this. I would like not to have to add another/new object to the form designer if I don't have to. Is there another easier option besides ContextMenuStrip?

Can someone please tell me how to open a PopupMenu in VB.NET?

Comment: Use Google for inane questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the form has a ContextMenuStrip control with menu items, try:

```
Me.ContextMenuStrip.Show(MousePosition)
```

Comment: @nate You want a PopupMenu without using a ContextMenuStrip?  You don't have to use the designer, but it just makes it easier.

Comment: Can you clarify that comment?

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill The original poster deleted their comment, so I'm missing the original reference.  You can just make a ContextMenuStrip through code, see [ContextMenuStrip Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)